# Find equation of plane formed by a point and line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

It is required to find the equation of a plane $Q$ formed by point $B\,(5,2,0)$ and  the line (d)
of parametric equation

$$
\begin{align}
x&=-2t+1\\
y&=2t-2 \\
z&=t
\end{align}$$

What is the easiest way to find the equation ? Answer is: $x-y+4z-3 = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to find the value of following determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
  (x-5) & (y-2) & (z-0)\\
  4 & 4 & 0\\
  -2 &2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ Note that the point $(-1,-2,0)$ is a point lying on the line and the vector $\langle -2,2,1\rangle$ is the leading vector for the line.

Comment: Forgot this way, which indeed is easier than mine...nice! +1

Comment: It is very kind of you for saying so. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with DonAntonio: I forgot this method! +1

Answer (score 2):

To get a plane in the form you want just solve linear equations:

If the plane is $\,\pi: ax+by+cz+d=0\,$ , then *it must be*" (with $\,L=$ the line):

$$\begin{align*}B\in\pi&\implies &\text{I}&\;\;\;&5a+2b+d=0\\
 t=0\implies (1,-2,0)\in L\cap \pi&\implies &\text{II}&\;\;\;&a-2b+d=0\\
t=1\implies (-1,0,1)\in L\cap\pi&\implies &\text{III}&\;\;\;&-a+c+d=0\\
t=-1\implies (3,-4,-1)\in L\cap\pi&\implies &\text{IV}&\;\;\;&3a-4b-c+d=0\end{align*}$$

Now some easy, albeit boring and slightly annoying, basic algebra:

$$\begin{align*}\text{I - II}&:\;\;\;4(a+b)=0\implies a=-b\\
\text{II}&:\;\;\;a+2a+d=0\implies d=-3a\\
\text{III}&:\;\;\;-a+c-3a=0\implies c=4a\end{align*}$$

Well, now just **choose** a nice non-zero value for any of the variables, say $\,a=1\,$ , and you get

$$x-y+4z-3=0$$

Note that **any** other non-zero value for $\,a\,$ would have given the very same plane but with proportional coefficients.